# Cumulative payment breakage SQL Server 2008 - revised

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Deleted my Original question as was not sure it was clear and decided that a fresh approach is probably the best way forward.

I have a table that holds details of payments we received. We'll call this tblPayments and it has a set up similar to (example)

```
DatePayment | AccountNo | value | TransactionNo
26/05/2014  | 123456    | 5.99  | 5845878987
26/06/2014  | 123456    | 5.99  | 5845879585
```

The data I have been tasked with creating a breakage report on a cumulative basis, with a criteria of 2 payments being missed for it to be classed as a breakage.

Example : Account 123456 pays 5.99 a month. He paid in June 2014 but then did not pay in July or August making this a breakage for August and continued not to pay until December meaning it was a cumulative breakage until Dec.

Previous query I used to calculate breakages was done using an `EXCEPT` Statement which did exactly what was needed when there was no cumulative figure needed. Would post the query I used but it is long and have had previous issues with its logic being understood. So going forward think a new more than likely intelligent way to get the data.

The desired output would be :

```
MonthBreakage | AccountNo | BreakageValue
01-Aug-2014   | 123456    | 5.99
01-Sep-2014   | 123456    | 5.99
01-Oct-2014   | 123456    | 5.99
01-Nov-2014   | 123456    | 5.99
01-Dec-2014   | NULL      | NULL
```

The nulls are just to highlight the record is no longer a breakage.

Any questions please let me know, i have hopefully been clear enough/

Comment: Just a side note: SQL is typically not very good at this sort of "tell me what's missing" type of question (since it was designed for querying the data you *do* have in the database). I will be interested to see the answers you get. But it may be easier to do this with procedural code. Which in your case means a stored procedure I guess.

Comment: Does December belong in the output? There was a payment for that month, wasn't there? Thus no breakage (which I think you indicate with NULL values) but then why show it? Why don't June and July show in the output?

Comment: @Turophile - I only showed Dec as a null as an example, the accounts 123456 would no longer be in the table for Dec onwards. I only want to show accounts that exist from the month of the breakage up until they pay

Comment: Does the amount (BreakageValue) come from the value of the last (previous) payment before the breakage?

Comment: @Turophile it does yeah but that field can be dropped if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer for you, but I'm out of time, so here's what I have so far:

```
with months as (
  select 1 as mkey 
  union 
  select 2 
  union 
  select 3 
  union
  select 4 
  union
  select 5 
  union
  select 6 
  union
  select 7 
  union
  select 8 
  union
  select 9 
  union
  select 10 
  union
  select 11 
  union
  select 12 
  )
select mkey, cast('2014-'+cast(mkey as varchar)+'-01' as date) as MonthBreakage, p.*
from months left outer join tblPayments as p on mkey = month(DatePayment)
where mkey > (select max(month(DatePayment)) from tblPayments)
```

You can see it [working in a fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76851/14).
Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just make one of two tweeks to the answer @Turophile gave.

Since union has to sort and pick out duplicates (even when there aren't any, it must check), so use a union all instead of a union in the months cte

or... rework months as

```
    with months as (
        select 1 as mkey 
        union all
        select mkey + 1
        from months
        where mkey < 12
    )
```